# change VM mac address durning salt-cloud provision

Tags: salt-stack, salt-cloud

I have a salt-cloud profile built up but want to be able to statically set the mac address during provision. I have a DHCP server that serves out specific IPs based on the server's mac address.
I'm connecting via vmware using salt 2015.5.8

Comment: Perhaps you should close this issue as it is not yet implement
https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/34035

Comment: [salt] tag is for a cryptography function.

Answer (score 0):

This option was implemented for salt version 2016.11.1.
If you can update your salt, do it.